# Unable to install steam

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, command-line, deb, steam

Ok so recently I logged into tf2 and saw that it supported linux. I'll be completely honest with you, first I was in it for the little penguin but after installing linux I'm actually starting to like it. The problem is I can't run steam. I can't even install it. I've tried installing it through the software center and its failed horribly saying:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved. 
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable.
Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

Then I tried downloading the steam.latest.deb but when I ran it in the software center I get this:

```
dependency is not satisfiable:libc6(>=2.15)
```

So finally I attempted to install the .deb file through the terminal using this code:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

and again I failed. After consulting with some friends who got it to work I entered suggested codes but all I've gotten so far is this I'll paste what my terminal says below if it helps. At this point I think I will uninstall Ubuntu 12.10 and see if it works on 12.04. Anyway here's the terminal:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add- architecture 1386
[sudo] password for bernardo: 
dpkg: error: unknown option --add-

$ sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
dpkg: error processing steam_latest.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
steam_latest.deb

$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcapi20-3 libgif4 libmpg123-0 libodbc1 libopenal-data libopenal1
  linux-headers-3.5.0-17 linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 unixodbc wine-gecko1.4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ cd /Downloads
bash: cd: /Downloads: No such file or directory
$ cd /Downloads sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
bash: cd: /Downloads: No such file or directory
$ sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
dpkg: error processing steam_latest.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam_latest.deb
```

Comment: It's `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` not `sudo dpkg --add -architecture i386` (no space between `--add` and `-architecture`). Is this a Wubi install? Because it's a known bug for them and shouldn't happen on a normal dual-boot install.